# Accessing float4/int4 elements using a loop in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm just writing my first CUDA program, and it's actually a rewrite of a C++ code. Now it deals with a lot of vector maths, so I use the float4 datatype which provides exactly what I need. However, the old code contains a lot of

```
float *vec;
vec = new float[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) vec[i] = ...;
```

Now with float4 all I can do is write a line for each .x,.y,.z,.w which I find a bit annoying. Is there no way of accessing float4 elements in a similar fashion, i.e.

```
float4 vec;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) vec[i] = ...;
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any hints on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a union, e.g.

```
typedef union {
    float4 vec;
    float a[4];
} U4;

U4 u;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) u.a[i] = ...;
```

For your arrays of `float4` you would just change the underlying type to `U4`.

*Note: technically it's UB to write to one variant of a union and then read from another, but it should work OK in this case and you don't need to worry about portability since this is CUDA-specific.*

Answer (score 2):

Probably not safe, but here is the easiest way.

```
float *vec;
vec = new float[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) vec[i] = ...;
float4 vec4 = *(float4 *)vec;
```

Or you can flip this

```
float4 vec4;
float *vec = (float *)&vec4; // Do not free this pointer
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) vec[i] = ...;
```

**EDIT**
The only way to directly store into an array would be like this

```
float4 vec4 = {val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]};
```

so if you have an array of float4s, you can do somehting like the following

```
float4 *vec4 = new float4[10];
float *vec = new float[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) vec[j] = j;
vec4[i] = (float4){vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], vec[3]}
}
```

Other than this, I cant figure an easier way.

Comment: Well yeah that might work, but as my float4 are all arrays themselves this could get quite nasty. I was just wondering whether there is some native operation that works directly on float4s. Thanks anyways.